# __proto__ in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

New to programming...I'm trying to learn about object inheritance in JavaScript.

I'm getting an error for the following code. It says:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getName in object [object Object]

Does `__proto__` (aka "dunder proto") not work in App Script? How can I set an inheritance to something other than the default "Object" without it?

```
function onPlay(){

//create an employee constructor
function Emp(last, first){
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.getName = function() {return(this.first+this.last);}
}

//create an employee
var emp1 = new Emp("Halpert", "Jim");

//log the employee's name
Logger.log(emp1.getName());


//create a manager constructor  
function Mgr(){
  this.salary = 100,000;
}

//managers are also employees
Mgr.__proto__ = Emp.prototype;

//create a manager
var mgr1 = new Mgr("Scott", "Michael");

//log the manager's name
Logger.log(mgr1.getName());  
}
```

Comment: Never use `__proto__`, it's deprecated! Btw, you wanted to change the prototype chain of `Mgr.prototype` not of the `Mgr` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than:

```
Mgr.__proto__ = Emp.prototype;
```

You probably want:

```
Mgr.prototype = Object.create(Emp);
```

The `__proto__` property is for mutating prototypes, and isn't necessarily available in all JavaScript engines. To set a prototype for your custom object constructor, you want to set the `prototype` object on the constructor function to an instance of the base class (with `Object.create` not calling the parent constructor unnecessarily).